# Cannot read property 'cacheViews' of undefined when navigating to a view in Durandal

Tags: durandal

This was working just fine. I think the error first appeared around the time I added a "cacheviews: true" to one of my compose items:

```
  <div id="leftCol">
      <section id="content-left">
        <div data-bind="compose: { model: leftColTree, preserveContext: true, cacheViews: true }"></div>
      </section>
  </div>
```

I have three views at present. I can refresh the current view and navigate to a different one, but once that's done I cannot then go to any other view without triggering the error in the title. I realise this is hard to diagnose, but if anyone has some advice on general things that cause this error then I'd be very grateful thanks!

EDIT
To clarify, this goes wrong in "composition.js" (line 352) which is the 2nd line below.

```
var instruction = binder.getBindingInstruction(context.activeView);
if(instruction.cacheViews != undefined && !instruction.cacheViews){
```

Comment: I'm guessing it's inside your own JavaScript somewhere, not in this binding nor inside of Durandal. Without code it's impossible to guess. At minimum, some more relevant code is necessary. Also, what code throws this error? A bit of debugging of the call stack should point out what is undefined, and that should bring you closer to the problem.

Comment: The error is happening in the Durandal "composition.js" file.  Have edited OP to show the point where it goes wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what's causing this. Are all your routes defined properly? Also I would check if the views have an activate callback, and if they have any other callbacks (canActivate, deactivate, etc.) make sure they are working correctly. Do you let Durandal handle the call to ko.applyBindings? If not, are you doing it yourself when you should be?

Comment: The odd thing is that if I refresh the page with the current url in, e.g. `http://localhost/mysite#page2` it works fine and the page loads. If I load up page 1, then click on the page 2 link, page 2 still loads but the console shows the error and I then cannot navigate to another page. The URL still changes when I click, but nothing happens.  I hoped that Rob or one of his team would know what this was, but it appears to be stumping everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Had this same error message at exactly the same spot in composition.js.

For me changing cacheViews from true to false in shell.html did the trick.

```
`<div>
    <header data-bind="compose: { view: 'nav' }"></header>
    <section id="content" class="main container-fluid"
        data-bind="router: { transition: 'entrance', cacheViews: true }">
    </section>
    <footer data-bind="compose: { view: 'footer' }"></footer>
</div>`
```

to this:

```
`<div>
    <header data-bind="compose: { view: 'nav' }"></header>
    <section id="content" class="main container-fluid"
        data-bind="router: { transition: 'entrance', cacheViews: false}">
    </section>
    <footer data-bind="compose: { view: 'footer' }"></footer>
</div>`
```